# Activity Recognition Client removing Updates

Tags: activity-recognition

When i tried to call `removeUpdates(PendingIntent)` from `ActivityRecognitionClient` it  throwed an exception(`Client Not connected`).So i checked `ActivityRecognitionClient.isConnected()` and then did `removeUpdates` .This Solved my problem.But then i saw something like `isConnecting()`.What should be done if the isConnecting returns true.

Comment: Please add some code, it's difficult to visualize problem with these atatements